# What is causing getElementbyID to fail

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm in brain dead mode. I'm trying to use google maps and i'm just starting out with my dummy html. The following code works, but if i put the map div into a container or simply change the name it fails not finding the ID

```
<body>
<!--           
    <section id="container">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </section>
   --> 
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script> 
        function initMap() {
        'use strict';

        var myLatLng = {lat: 14.79445, lng: 120.271364};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            zoom: 6,
            center: myLatLng
        });
        }
    </script>  

    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURKEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>

</body>
```

If i take out the comments and run this with the container div, the getElementByID fails.

If i change the id from map to map2 (in both places) the getelement fails.

I know i'm doing something very stupid, but i just don't see it.

Dev environment is brackets, pushing a chrome browser. (my key removed from the API call)

Comment: So do you have both divs with the id when it fails or just one? Unclear how the commented out HTML is in play here.

Comment: It's the container not having a height that's the problem. See the accepted answer. It really is a simple fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Google example, you will find that you need to set map's height to be 100% of its container. Here's the CSS from their own example:

```
html, body { 
  height: 100%; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
} 
#map { 
  height: 100%;
}
```

By wrapping it in a container you caused map's 100% to be `0` which is height of its parent div (`#container`). The simplest fix here is:

```
#container, #map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5bg9gkL9/2/.

Comment: It's sad when you just can't see the forest through the trees. Yes, that's the problem. Simple fix and all is moving forward. Thanks for jogging the brain cells.

Answer (score 1):

> If i change the id from map to map2 (in both places)

This is your problem.

In any DOM (HTML, SVG, XML etc.) an id MUST BE UNIQUE. By unique I mean that only one element must have a specific id. If two or more elements have the same id that's considered an error.

HTML, being a very lenient language, does not throw error messages when developers make mistakes. Instead browsers automatically try to guess what you mean.

There is no standard that specifies what a browser should do if there are two or more identical ids. So `getElementById` can do whatever it wants in such cases. Different browsers may do different things.

The failure is not `getElementById`. The failure is two elements having the same id.

For what you are trying to do use `class` and `getElementsByClassName` instead. Take note: it's `elementS` by class name, plural.

Comment: By "in both places" he probably meant html and javascript.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, Tomasz has it right, i was indicating that i made the change in the HTML and the JS